# formatting lose when showing a previously hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So my webpage shows a new div when you click on an existing div. This hidden div has exactly the same formatting as the existing visible div, but when it is made to appear, all of that formatting is lost and I can't quite work out why. Here's the code:

```
<div id="visible" class="visibleDiv" onclick="expandItem()">
   Stuff here
</div>

<div id="invisible" class="hiddenDiv">
    Stuff here
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
function expandItem() {

if (document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == '') {
    document.getElementById("invisible").style.display = 'block';

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean it has the same "formatting"? CSS? Have you tried changing `display` to `inline`, instead of `block`?

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
<div id="visible" class="visibleDiv" onclick="expandItem()">
    Stuff here
</div>
<div id="invisible" style="display:none;" class="hiddenDiv">
    Stuff here
</div>
```

And make change in javascript

```
function expandItem() {
if (document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById("invisible").style.display = 'block';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah this should fetch the solution

```
function expandItem() {
if (document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == 'none' || document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == '') {
    document.getElementById("invisible").style.display = 'block';

}
```

this line

```
document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == ''
```

is irrelavent , the main code to be executed is

```
document.getElementById("invisible").style.display == 'none'
```