# Tablerow formatting messed up by display:block

Tags: css, jsp

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191860/formatting-lose-when-showing-a-previously-hidden-div). But using display block is what's messing it up.

I'm wondering how I can make table rows appear and disappear, without messing up the formatting.

Currently this is what I'm using:

```
<%String fieldsDisplay = (type.equals("Add")) ? "display:block" : "display:none";%>
```

I'm using this as a style in my table row. But when I add this style, the formatting gets messed up. There are currently three columns and the spacing between them just gets removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the table-row display property instead.

```
<%String fieldsDisplay = (type.equals("Add")) ? "display:table-row" : "display:none";%>
```